# what is wrong with the code as i am unable to print 3 and 2

Tags: java, range, primes

I am unable to get all the prime numbers printed .can someone help me with this .I get all the values except 2 and 3 . It starts with 5 .

```java
public static void primesinRange(int n) {
  int flag=1;
  int i, j=2;
  
  for(i=2;i<=n;i++) { 
    if(n==1 || n==0) {
           continue;
    }

    if(n==2) {
      flag=1;
      continue;
    }

    flag=1;

    for(j=2;j<=Math.sqrt(n);j++) { 
      if((i%j)==0) {
        flag=0;
        break;
      }
    } 
        
    if(flag==1) {
      System.out.print(i+ " ");
    }  
  }   
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properbly before posting it

Comment: It is a good time to learn how to debug your code. It is very helpful if you want to find out why your code is not working

Comment: Yes, thankyou. I will keep that in mind. New here ,still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the condition of your inner for-loop from

```
j<=Math.sqrt(n)
```

to

```
j<=Math.sqrt(i)
```

Otherwise for sufficiently large values of `n` this range will include the small `i` values.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for responding . Could you please explain a little bit more about changing  n to i?